# Avoid showing Spring Framework specific services as part of Swagger interface

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I am using spring-boot-starter-parent 1.3.3.RELEASE. I am unable to disable the following endpoints in Swagger UI.

Need To Disable:-

```
Entity Metadata Services
profile-controller
repository-controller
```

I disabled the following endpoints using the code..

Disabled endpoints:-

```
environment-manager-mvc-endpoint
generic-postable-mvc-endpoint
restart-mvc-endpoint
```

Code:-

```
public Docket appHierarchyServiceApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(Predicates.not(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("org.springframework.boot")))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any()).build()
```

[image]

How to disable the profile and repository controller in Swagger UI??

Kindly provide your inputs.

Answer (score 2):

use a regex within .paths(...)

I use the following :

```
.paths(PathSelectors.regex(""^/(?!error|autoconfig|beans|configprops|dump|info|mappings|trace|env|metrics).*$""))
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply @mbtdoor!! I have updated an image which we unable to hide from swagger UI. How to disable repository-controller from swagger UI?? kindly provide your inputs..

Comment: you may use `spring.data.rest.basePath=/api` then just add api into the regexp expression as above.

Answer (score 2):

I use these:

`.apis(Predicates.not(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("org.springframework.boot")))
                .apis(Predicates.not(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("org.springframework.cloud")))
                .apis(Predicates.not(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc")))`