# How to hide repository-controller from Swagger UI

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I am using spring-boot-starter-parent 1.3.3.RELEASE. I am unable to disable repository controller in Swagger UI

[image]

I have disabled the other unwanted endpoints using this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40238166/avoid-showing-spring-framework-specific-services-as-part-of-swagger-interface).

How to disable repository-controller from swagger UI?? kindly provide your inputs

If use the follow, it returns only the search repository which written by me but I need the entity endpoints also. Those entities endpoints will return by spring defaults.

```
.apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("bla.blablah.bla"))
```

Kindly refer the image: [image]

Answer (score 1):

When initializing your `Docket` in your `Application` class, you can filter package names easily, therefore it will create your api for only given base package:

```
@Bean
public Docket swaggerSpringMvcPlugin(){
    return new Docket( DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2 )//
            .select().apis( RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage( "com.blabla.bla" ) )//
            .build();
}
```

Another solution:

```
return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).apiInfo(apiInfo()).select() 
          .apis(Predicates.not(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("org.springframework.boot")))
             .build();
```

Another solution that negates a specific package:

```
return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).apiInfo(apiInfo()).select() 
          .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("org.springframework.boot").negate())
             .build();
```

Comment: Thanks @Ozdemir. I know, it will work as expected but I need the entity related endpoints which spring boot(org.springframework.data) returns then How do I handle this?

Comment: @SST why dont you just type your base package into that setting, therefore springboot packages won't be get into it, but anyway I've provided another solution for you, check the answer again.

Comment: No. This is not working. If I put which you are provided, It will not returned Entity Controller.

Comment: But, you have to provide your own entity controller's base package with Predicates builder after excluding spring's

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same issue by creating my own `Predicate` and adding them to the `Docket` configuration. You can get the Group name (repository-controller) from RequestHandler Object.

My code:

```
@Bean
public Docket api() { 
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)  
        .select()                                  
          .apis(GroupNameFilter())
          .build();                                           
}

private Predicate<RequestHandler> GroupNameFilter(){
    return new Predicate<RequestHandler>() {
        @Override
        public boolean apply(RequestHandler input) {
            return !input.groupName().equals("repository-controller");  
        }
  };
}
```